# Error while fetching using tOracleRow Talend

Tags: talend

I am trying to create a Table using tOracleRow.I am trying to create Table with The Below statement :

```
DROP TABLE TEMP_ORDERS;
CREATE Table TEMP_ORDERS AS
select a.ITEM_NAME,b.MANUFACTURER_NAME from ITEMS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN MANUFACTURERS b
ON a.MANUFACTURER_ID=b.MANUFACTURER_ID;
```

[image]

Now the Problem is this query is running fine sql Developer.Whereas when i am pasting this query in `tOracleRow` or `tOracleinput` it is saying that invalid char.Then I tried removing the `;` but it is saying that SQL Command not properly ended.

[image]

Comment: When I am not giving ";" it is giving the error [statistics] connecting to socket on port 3686
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tOracleInput_1
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character The sample data of two Table is

Comment: please copy and past both error in your post (with and without `;`). have you tried just with the first line `Drop table` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to have a `tOracleRow` execute multiple statements at once.

You need to provide an "additional Parameter" to the connection you are using: `allowMultiQueries=true`

**New Connection Wizard:**

[image: New Connection Wizard]

You also need to use a `BEGIN END` block in your `tOracleRow` component if you are using multiple statements. You need to have an semicolon also after the closing `END` keyword.

**Multiple statements with BEGIN END block:**

[image: Multiple statements with BEGIN END block]

Answer (score 1):

In your query you are using a DML as well as multiple queries. So you need to do the following to make the job work:

i) Open the oracle connection using tOracleConnection. In additional parameters set `allowMultiQueries=true`

ii)Use tOracle row to execute the queries. Separate the queries with semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
"
DROP TABLE TEMP_ORDERS;
CREATE Table TEMP_ORDERS AS
select a.ITEM_NAME,b.MANUFACTURER_NAME from ITEMS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN MANUFACTURERS b
ON a.MANUFACTURER_ID=b.MANUFACTURER_ID
"
```

Without the `;` at the end of the request

Comment: I have tried in your way.Now it is giving like this                         Exception in component tOracleInput_1
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

 at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)

Comment: I have tried just using only DROP Table.Now when i didn't use ";" it gave me [statistics] connecting to socket on port 3420
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tOracleInput_1
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01003: no statement parsed and when i am using ";" it is giving    [statistics] connecting to socket on port 3871
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tOracleInput_1
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: you should use select statements in tOracleInput component. Can you try to run your multi-line statement in tOracleRow without giving ; at the last statement...does it works..can you try with more simple statements like two drop statements instead of one drop and one create. Also you might want to try to use / as separator of individual sql queries in toracleRow component..

Answer (score 0):

Rather using  **tOracleRow**, You can use both **tOracleInput** and **tOracleOutput** component and then use only select query 
"select a.ITEM_NAME,b.MANUFACTURER_NAME from ITEMS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN MANUFACTURERS b
ON a.MANUFACTURER_ID=b.MANUFACTURER_ID
"  as tOracleInput query and then select "Drop and create table" under Action on table of  **tOracleOutput**

Answer (score 0):

the purpose of tOracleRow is to execute a single statement for each talend record flow.. so if you give the DROP & CREATE statements in one tOracleRow it is not going to work as per my knowledge..

You can try these below options.

--> separate your two statements into two tOracleRow components Or
--> Create a PLSQL Block and use that in tOracleRow like below
"BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE TEMP_ORDERS';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE Table TEMP_ORDERS AS
select a.ITEM_NAME,b.MANUFACTURER_NAME from ITEMS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN MANUFACTURERS b
ON a.MANUFACTURER_ID=b.MANUFACTURER_ID';
END;"

Let me know if it works out

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two separate `tOracleRow` components. It is not possible to use this component like a input shell or tool like SQL Developer where you can execute more than one command.

The first one will only hold the drop statement without the ending semicolon:

```
"DROP TABLE TEMP_ORDERS"
```

The second one will only hold the create statement, also without the semicolon:

```
"CREATE Table TEMP_ORDERS AS 
select a.ITEM_NAME,b.MANUFACTURER_NAME from ITEMS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN MANUFACTURERS b
ON a.MANUFACTURER_ID=b.MANUFACTURER_ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is based on the previous post.
1) in the oracle connection you have to include the "allowMuliQueries=true".
2) each query needs to use a `BEGIN END` and also inserted inside an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` ->

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE'DROP TABLE TEMP_ORDERS';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE'CREATE Table TEMP_ORDERS AS
select a.ITEM_NAME,b.MANUFACTURER_NAME from ITEMS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN MANUFACTURERS b
ON a.MANUFACTURER_ID=b.MANUFACTURER_ID';
END
;
```